# A function with itself as a default argument

Tags: python

Defaults are parsed at definition. So this will not work

```
def f(x, func = f):
    if x<1:
        return x
    else:
        return x + func(x-1)
```

I did find a way, though. I start with some dummy function

```
def a(x):
    return x

def f(x, func=a):
    if x < 1:
        return x
    else:
        return x + func(x-1)
```

And then issue

```
f.__defaults__ = (f,)
```

Obviously awkward. Is there another way or is this bad python? If it's bad, can you explain why? Where will it break things?

In any case, it works:

```
In [99]: f(10)
Out[99]: 55

In [100]: f(10, f)
Out[100]: 55

In [101]: f(10, lambda x : 2*x)
Out[101]: 28
```

Comment: Why don't you just use `None`?

Comment: Why would you even want to do it? It smells like an XY problem. What are you really trying to do?

Comment: This is more like recursion. You could just replace `func` with `f` in the function

Comment: Making it an argument with a default value implies that there are cases where you want to override the default. What's the use case for this?

Comment: @Barmar, maybe they are trying to write a generic recursive method?

Comment: @pat But if you have to explicitly name the function in the argument list, it's no more generic than calling the function explicitly.

Comment: @Barmar.  You are right.  I am just trying to guess what the asker is trying to do.

Comment: @Barmar, it is just as written. A function that is recursive by default unless instructed otherwise by specifying a different function. I know there are other ways to do the same. I'm just wondering if this strange way is legitimate...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To elaborate on Andrea Corbellini's suggestion, you can do something like this:

```
def f(x, func=None):
    if func is None:
        func = f

    if x < 1:
        return x
    else:
        return x + func(x-1)
```

It is a pretty standard idiom in Python to implement the actual defaults inside of the function and defining the default parameter as `None` (or some private sentinel object in case `None` is valid input), due to problems with mutable default values such as `list` objects.